# Como mostrar un registro en C# y SQL Server para despues modificarlo

Tags: c#, sql-server, select, stored-procedure, update

Estoy realizando las operaciones CRUD sobre clientes, tengo una ventana donde se muestran todos los clientes en un DataGridView y 3 botones (agregar, editar y eliminar) en el editar quisiera poder seleccionar un id en el DataGrid, darle clic a modificar y que se muestre dicho registro en los textbox para despues modificarlos
[image: Clientes]

Comment: Te invito a leer [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Te recomiendo agregar el código que estas usando para mostrar la información en la tabla.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay varias formas de hacer eso, la mas simple es la siguiente.

Asumiendo que tienes 3 celdas NumeroCliente,Nombre,RFC en tu datagridview1 y 3 ttextboxes txt_numeroCliente, txt_nombre, txt_rfc

Primero desabilitas la propiedad MultiSelect de tu datagridview.

En el evento click de tu boton editar pondrias lo siguiente

```
//evitar que el usuario seleccione mas de una fila a la vez
dataGridView1.MultiSelect = false;

//Opcional: seleccionar toda la fila en vez de una sola columna
dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;

//usa una condicion if para asegurarte que el usuario selecciono al menos una fila
if(dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0) 
{
   txt_numeroCliente.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["NumeroCliente"].Value.toString();

   txt_nombre.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["Nombre"].Value.toString();

  txt_rfc.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["RFC"].Value.toString();
}
```

Reemplaza el nombre tus celdas y de tus textboxes y listo. Si tus celdas no tienen nombre, puedes usar indices 0,1,2 etc.